# Monetary Denominations with Array Formulas

Tags: google-sheets

I have developed a monthly budget sheet that works well in Excel. It lets me break down a paycheck to the denominations of each item the paycheck will cover.

Example: Focus on January (Enero) on the Budget tab. If one earns $1,000 on 1/1/17, the info will be filled out as shown in the range `G3:G5`. Then I want to see the denominations for that paycheck, I will mark an "X" in `G6`. The Denomination section (`A4:B11`) will show the data.

When one gets the paycheck for 1/15/17, the same process will be used. However, the denomination will not show for the next paycheck unless the X is marked in H7.

For some reason, the array formulas on the Denominacion tab would work for all months in Excel, but not for all months in Google Sheets.

The code is (starting in cell `B4` and down in Column B on Denominacion tab):

```
=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Budget!"&$B$2&A4)),"",INDIRECT("Budget!"&IF(RIGHT($B$2,1)="Z",CHAR(CODE(LEFT($B$2,1))+1),LEFT($B$2,1))&CHAR(65+MOD(CODE(RIGHT($B$2,1))+1-65,26))&A4))
```

Maybe the rest of the formulas on the same tab needs some fixing too?

Here is the Googlesheet: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15prf8yPAk2o3gIfs4H8nCZpRRmELCcBZnEiNoXdU0fQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I imagine this question will be better suited for [webapps.se].

Comment: Welcome to SO. The Denomication tab is mostly blank, it's that what needs fixing I suppose? can you explain what that tab does?

Comment: Hi Robin, the Denomination tab should populate if I marked an X in G7 on the Budget tab and there is a value in G6. Yes, the denomination tab is what needs fixing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now found the culprit! It is at the end of the formula in Cell B4 on Denomination Tab. I had removed `&CHAR(65+MOD(CODE(RIGHT($B$2,1))+1-65,26))` from the formula below:

`=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Budget!"&$B$2&A4)),"",INDIRECT("Budget‌​!"&IF(RIGHT($B$2,1)=‌​"Z",CHAR(CODE(LEFT($‌​B$2,1))+1),LEFT($B$2‌​,1))`**&CHAR(65+MOD(COD‌​E(RIGHT($B$2,1))+1-6‌​5,26))**`&A4))`

So now, the working formula is:

`=IF(ISBLANK(INDIRECT("Budget!"&$B$2&A4)),"",INDIRECT("Budget‌​!"&IF(RIGHT($B$2,1)<‌​"Z",CHAR(CODE(LEFT($‌​B$2,1))+1),LEFT($B$2‌​,1))&A4))`